# Django container can't communicate with postgres container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

My Django container can't communicate with my postgres container.

In my django settings file:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB', 'mydatabase'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER', 'myuser'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD', 'mypassword'),
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: mydatabase
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  django:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  data:
```

I can confirm that creating both containers individually works by running `docker-compose up -d django` and `docker-compose up -d db`. By "working I mean" that I see the output that the db container is being created, and I can, for example, access the website from the `django` container in the browser.

But when I try to run migrations in the django container (as part of the `django` service's Dockerfile), I get

```
c4x@debian ~/repos/eventregistration (dockerize)$ docker-compose up --build
Creating network "eventregistration_default" with the default driver
Building django
[+] Building 49.2s (13/13) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                               docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 611B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11                                                                                                                                              5.8s
 => [1/9] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11@sha256:4e5e9b05dda9cf699084f20bb1d3463234446387fa0f7a45d90689c48e204c83                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                           1.3s
 => => transferring context: 153.20MB                                                                                                                                                                       1.2s
 => CACHED [2/9] RUN mkdir -p /code                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [3/9] WORKDIR /code                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [4/9] COPY . /code                                                                                                                                                                                      1.1s
 => [5/9] RUN apt update && apt install gettext -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                                                                                                           8.4s
 => [6/9] RUN pip install --upgrade pip                                                                                                                                                                     3.8s 
 => [7/9] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                                                                                                                                              26.0s 
 => [8/9] RUN python manage.py compilemessages --settings=eventregistration.settings.development                                                                                                            1.5s 
 => ERROR [9/9] RUN python manage.py migrate --settings=eventregistration.settings.development               

[ long stacktrace ]

1.179 django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
1.179 
------
Dockerfile:20
--------------------
  18 |     
  19 |     EXPOSE 8000/tcp
  20 | >>> RUN python manage.py migrate --settings=eventregistration.settings.development
  21 |     CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=eventregistration.settings.development
  22 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python manage.py migrate --settings=eventregistration.settings.development" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'django' failed to build : Build failed
```

Note that there's no output regarding the creation of the database container in there.

Does this configuration look good to you in general? Could you think on anything that I could try?

Comment: A Dockerfile can never connect to another container; you can't `RUN` a migration script from a Dockerfile.  The linked question describes several alternatives, with the most-automated option being to run migrations from a script in your image's `ENTRYPOINT`.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing your code to one of my projects, the only difference I'm seeing is that I added a `healthcheck` to my `db` service in the compose file:

```
  db:
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U db_user"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10

  web:
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: true
```

`db_user` is the user name that you want to run health checks with.

I'm pretty sure I added this for similar issues, where Django was a bit too eager to connect to the database before it was *really* ready, despite the `depends_on` entries.

Comment: I have added this healthcheck, but the output is still the same. Please see my updated answer, I have included more of the error message. Note that if I include `condition: service_healthy` I get:
```c4x@debian ~/repos/eventregistration (dockerize)$ docker-compose up --build
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 24, column 18
```